# issue duplicating nodes with gkcomponents within Xcode scene editor

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sprite-kit, editor

Simple question and I haven't been able to find a solution for. I'm working on a project, I build out my scenes in the scene editor, and I'm heavily using components that I then add to nodes within the editor. Some of these nodes I need a bunch of copies of them. When you copy and paste, or duplicate the node in the editor, go to the components inspector on the new node, the components don't copy over.

Is there a setting or a way that I can get it to copy over the components as well?

Would save a bunch of time, building out scenes...

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't copy the components with the nodes in the editor at this time.

Comment: Is it only going to one?

Comment: If you highlight multiple nodes, and try to add a component, none of them get it...

Comment: Do you still have XCode 8?  Maybe they broke it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using xcode9.0, it has a bug that the copied file cannot be added to the project, if it only needs to be updated to the new version

Comment: I'm not copying a file. I'm just copying a node within the scene editor.